# Jquery timeout on each

Tags: jquery, timeout, delay, each

I'm trying to write a jQuery function to change out href of a link, but I'm not quite sure how to do it. I've implemented a slider, but I have a link which lives outside of the slider (outsideLink) which needs to change as the slider changes.

I'm trying to achieve the following:

```
for each link in sliderList
     get currentLink.href
     outsideLink.href = currentLink.href
     wait 3 seconds
     repeat
end
```

I'm not sure how to implement the delay when I'm going through a list of items though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd approach this a bit different, just update it when the slider changes like this:

```
$('.selector').slider({
  slide: function(event, ui) {
   //outsideLink.href = currentLink.href
  }
});
```

[You can see a full list of slider events here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#event-slide)